# Count number of bits to convert one integer to another integer

Tags: python, integer, bitwise, edit-distance

Return the number of bits (N) that will need to be changed in order to convert an integer(X), into another integer(Y).

> Constraint: 0 <= X <= Y <= 2**128
>
> Example:
>
> X = 1, Y = 2 => N = 2
>
> X = 2, Y = 3 => N = 1
>
> X = 0, Y = 4 => N = 1

I have written following code, how to improve it?

```
def bit_diff(n1,n2):
    cmn_d = n1 & n2
    all_d = n1 | n2
    diff = all_d - cmn_d
    cnt = 0
    while diff:
        if diff & 1:
            cnt+=1
        diff>>=1
    return cnt

print bit_diff(1,2)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> cmn_d = n1 & n2
> all_d = n1 | n2
> diff = all_d - cmn_d
> ```

There is an operator for that:

```
diff = n1 ^ n2
```

---

Having found the bits that differ, you want to count the set bits of `diff`, also known as the *population count* or the *Hamming weight*. The approach you use is simple and valid, but there are higher performing approaches which parallelise it (see [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive) and following sections).

However, the standard approaches for the fastest parallel implementations without direct hardware support are based on fixed-width integers, and they typically go to 32 bits or 64 bits; since your specification says that you want to support 128-bit integers, you'll have to extrapolate, although it's not that hard.

Answer (score 4):

Style-wise, you could work on your variable naming ([realizing that naming is one of the two hardest things in programming](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)).

`cmn_d` could be `common_digits`, `all_d` `all_digits` and `cnt` `count`. This would make it slightly easier to read

Python also has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends using spaces around operators, so you would write `diff >>= 1` and `count += 1`.

---

Performance wise, your code is already quite fast (not that surprising, considering that it does just bit-shifts), so I don't think a different approach is needed here, although the improvement in [@PeterTaylors answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/161109/98493) is slightly faster:

```
+----+----+--------+--------------+
| n1 | n2 | Harsha | Peter Taylor |
+----+----+--------+--------------+
|  1 |  2 | 322 ns | 276 ns       |
|  2 |  3 | 255 ns | 202 ns       |
|  0 |  4 | 389 ns | 326 ns       |
+----+----+--------+--------------+
```

So, unless you need to run this more than a few million times per second on small cases, your implementation should be fine (with the small modification of using `n1 ^ n2`).

Comment: There is nowhere near enough context in the question to say whether it's worth trying to improve performance or not. The first rule of optimisation says that it isn't, but if it does turn out to be the major bottleneck then a) the parallelisation approach should run about 16 times faster in the average case assuming uniformity; b) the benchmarks should use at least one case where `n1 ^ n2` is 128 bits long, to cover that average case.

Comment: @PeterTaylor True, in general. However, anything that runs under a micro-second is probably going to be fine (unless it is a *really* tight loop). But to know that it is, you need to profile it (which is usually the third rule of optimization, always profile before considering optimizations). So my post is basically saying exactly what you are saying: probably there are no optimizations needed, but I added the information that now you can decide *if* it is needed (do you need to perform this calculation more than a million times a second on simple cases?).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Re the benchmark cases, I just used the examples given by the OP, but sure, if you have a better benchmark case, I'd be happy to include it...

Answer (score 0):

Python is slow compared to C, but it'll work:

```
def bit_diff(n1,n2):
    i = n1 ^ n2
    c = 0
    while i:
        i &= i - 1
        c += 1
    return c

print bit_diff(1,2)
```

This is faster:

```
def bit_diff(n1,n2):
    i = n1 ^ n2
    c = bin(i).count("1")
    return c

print (bit_diff(34247483290175849302758**6500,43287543289074382905743**6500))

2506164
[Finished in 1.0s]
```

You can also use lookup tables if you need to do this faster, 
Google the terms "Hamming weight" and "popcount".
SSE4 includes an instruction POPCNT, if you use C it will be very fast.